# Python pandas Groupby() function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, merge

I'm looking to use values from a dataframe generated through `Groupby()`. The command I wrote was:

```py
pitcher_avg = total_data.groupby(['PitcherID','PitchType'])['ReleaseSpeed'].mean()
```

The `pitcher_avg` output was:

```
PitcherID  PitchType
80027      CF           86.022476
           CH           80.846935
           FB           89.614138
           SI           86.953833
           SL           80.533818
```

My next step is taking the values in the right-hand column, and merging them into a new dataframe on the condition that the PitcherID matched the PitcherID in the new dataframe. For example:

```
           GameDate  PitcherID    ...            CF            CH
0        2018-03-29      80027    ...     86.022476     80.846935
1        2018-03-29      80027    ...     86.022476     80.846935
2        2018-03-29      80027    ...     86.022476     80.846935
3        2018-03-29      80027    ...     86.022476     80.846935
4        2018-03-29      80027    ...     86.022476     80.846935
```

Is this possible? I've been trying `np.where` and `pd.merge` commands, but nothing has worked yet. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do `.reset_index()` and rename new column after the groupy by. Merge should work after that. You can specify in merge on which columns to merge i.e.
`df_original.merge(grouped_results_df, how ='left', indicator =True, on = ['PitcherID','PitcherType','NewColumn'])`

Comment: Did it worked for you ? If it did just accept the answer please